# if statement works with any input

Tags: c

i'm learning `c programming language`, i have been told to make a password code but whenever i compile it , it gives me `"correct"` even tho its not. this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int s;

  scanf("%d", &s);

  if (s = 1234) {
    printf("the password is correct");

  } else {
    printf("the password is incorrect");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

also can someone give me a link where they have beginner tasks for me ?
i enrolled in an embedded system course and i had no experience for C , so i was told to learn C 1st

Comment: Seems like a typo `if(s=1234)` -> `if(s==1234)`.

Comment: `==` is comparison, `=` is assignment. With a sufficiently high warning level, the compiler will likely warn you when you use the wrong one.

Comment: Or better, `if (1234 == s)`, since that way, the compiler will catch the error for you if you use `=` by mistake.

Comment: @Ray: ["Yoda conditions"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/16908/7740) are a matter of some debate.

Comment: @ton this question does not belong here. It's a lazy question with no research behind it. Any competent compiler would have warned about this particular mistake.

Comment: @FredLarson Or better, "A matter of some debate, 'Yoda conditions' are."  But yes, there is an arguable stylistic tradeoff. I personally find eliminating potential bugs to be more than worth it, but phrasing the expression this way is not a hard requirement.

Comment: @＿Static＿assert And I'm sure that, as a complete beginner, he already know precisely which compilers would issue that warning. And even if he doesn't, surely we can expect him to just google `C "=" vs. "=="`, even though he doesn't know that that line is the one at fault.  Put yourself in his position: if all you know is that the if statement doesn't seem to be working right, exactly what research do you do that will make you realize what the problem is? He's a novice who's trying to learn. Helping him is what this site is for.

Comment: @＿Static＿assert *"Would you welcome a question asking 'why doesn't int i ======= 10 work'?"*  If that was a standard mathematical notation, and *also* a legal expression in C, *and* it meant something different in each case, *and* was as common a source of confusion as `if (i = 10)` is? Then *yes*.

Comment: @＿Static＿assert  easy man none is competing here , also if you didn't like my question you are allowed to ignore it , i have zero experience with programming and i just started it today using random youtube playlist

Comment: also you can see that i clearly asked for some exercise so i can improve my knowledge

Comment: @JosephVictor [Kernighan & Ritchie 2nd edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) used to be the standard introductory (and reference) book for C, and contains exercises. It's for an older version of the language now, and the programming style it uses has fallen a bit out of favor, but I can't think of any better starting points. Just be sure to read up on the changes the C99 and C11 standards made once you've learned the basics; there weren't too many changes. *Avoid* anything by Herb Schildt; his books are infamous for being very clearly written, but inaccurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are using wrong the equal sign. It must be == not = in the if statement. Also you have to include

```
 #include <stdio.h>
```