# How to get rid of a number after the result being shown?

Tags: c++, calculation

I have to write a program that calculates the formula inputted from the user. For example:"**input: 1+2**", "**output: 3**", but I keep getting a number after the answer like this:"**input: 1+2**", "**output: 3-12**". How do I get rid of that **-12** behind the **3**? And why is it giving me that number? Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n,m;
    char x;
    cin>>n>>x>>m;
    if(x='+'){
        cout<<n+m;
    }
    if(x='-'){
        cout<<n-m;
    }
    if(x='*'){
        cout<<n*m;
    }
    
}
```

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Did your compiler give you a warning? If so, you need to pay attention to it. If not, you need to either get a better compiler or learn how to get your compiler to give you diagnostic information.

Comment: I use Dev-C++ and it didn't give me any warnings, maybe I need to change some settings?

Comment: "_How do I get rid of that_" ... "condition"? That's the logic you add to the program.

Comment: We get this asked every other day and people are going to [claim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62457075/if-statement-works-with-any-input#comment110458546_62457075) that I am being unfriendly to beginners, while I am in fact only against *lazy* questions that seem to haven't bothered to check how the syntax works or even looked around to see if anyone has asked that exact same thing before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression in the `if` statement:

```
if(x='+')
```

doesn't compare `x` to `+`, but instead assigns `+` to `x`. That means every single one of your `if` statements evaluates to true, and you get 3 numbers as output, i.e. 3, -1, and 2.

The correct way to do a comparison is:

```
if(x == '+')
```

If you turn on all your warnings, the compiler will tell you that you did something wrong.

Comment: with `g++` the warning is "suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value"

Comment: Exactly. If you want assignment, use extra `()`. But in this case you don't. The compiler is simply saying that the code is likely to be a mistake. (which it is)

Answer (score -1):

First you made the '=' operation this will make the value assign to the variable so you must made it like this;

```
if (x == '*')
```

It will solve the problem.

Second in the '-' operation you kind of will have a problem when the first number is less than second number it will get you a negative number to solve it you will make a simple if statement to prevent this from happening;

```
if (x=='-'){
   if(n>m)
     cout << n-m << endl;
   else
     cout << m-n << endl;
}
```

so you tell the computer that if the first number bigger than the second number so subtract the first number,
else if first number is less than the second number then, subtract the second number from the first number, by this you will prevent the user form getting negative number if you want.